# EXTJS 4 - Global exception listener

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, extjs-mvc

I have a situation where I am making `ajax` requests to a server from various Ext `gridpanel` etc. In an Admin area.

The logged in user will be logged out if there is no activity for eg. 5 minutes which is normal.

In this case the server sends back a redirect `403` to the login page.

Right now I am inserting a:

```
listeners: {
    exception: function(proxy, response, operation, eOpts) {
        if (response.status == '403')
            window.location = 'login';
    }
}
```

To every `store's` proxy which is a little overkill.

Could someone be kind enough and let me know how I could add a listener to all communications between ExtJS and server?

I am using the MVC Application Architecture so it could probably be a one liner in the `controller.js` or `app.js`.

Thanks

Answer (score 29, accepted):

In the beginning of your app insert the following snippet. With this **EVERY** response, whether it's from a store or a form or ..., will be checked and redirect to login page.

```
Ext.Ajax.on('requestexception', function (conn, response, options) {
    if (response.status === 403) {
        window.location = 'login';
    }
});
```

Comment: funny, we both were answering this question at the same time and both have given the same answer. So it must be correct.

Answer (score 8):

I'm not really sure if this will catch all ajax requests but assuming you're using AjaxProxy for all communication with the server it should work:
handle the 'requestexception' event in the Ext.Ajax singleton
something like this

```
Ext.Ajax.on('requestexception', function(conn, response, options, eOpts) {
    //your error handling here
});
```

I haven't tried it but if you do, could you post an update here?

Answer (score 7):

A more complete solution, wherein it will be a catch-all is this:

```
Ext.util.Observable.observe(Ext.data.Connection, {
    requestexception: function(conn, response, options) {
        if(response.status == '403')
            window.location = 'login';
    }
});
```

This is because the underlying class, `Ext.data.Connection` is used not only in `Ext.Ajax` but as well as the `Ext.data.Proxy` that is used by `Ext.data.Store, Ext.data.Model`. This handles exceptions on such calls as `store.load()` and `model.save()`. This should be a more complete catch-all handler.

See more details in [my blog post.](http://javanojutsu.blogspot.com.au/2014/11/global-exception-handling-ajax-calls-in_25.html)

Comment: Ext.util.Observable.observe is not a function in Ext JS 5.x. You have to use Ext.Ajax.on

Comment: No you don't, and yes in Ext JS 5.0.1 `typeof Ext.util.Observable.observe` will outputs `"function"`